# Copy PasteSpecial xlPasteAll vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

tengo un problema con un macro en Excel, en Excel 2016 ocupo esta linea de instrucciones para copiar un rango de datos de una hoja a otra:

```
Range("A" & (Row - 2), "C" & (Row - 2)).Copy
Worksheets("RESULTADO").Range("A" & filaPegar).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

En las pruebas que realizo me funciona perfectamente, pero intento ejecutar la macro en otra PC con Excel 2013 y no me realiza la operacion.

No usé ninguna libreria en especial (al menos no referencie ninguna), ademas no me marca error, solo no me realiza la operacion de forma correcta.

Algo estaré haciendo mal o porque no me corre el macro en otra maquina.?

Comment: ¿Dónde estás ejecutando el código? ¿En Excel 2013? ¿O en otra app de office?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a ser explicito al usar range : `Sheets("ORIGEN").Range("A" & (Row - 2), "C" & (Row - 2)).Copy`

Tambien puedes probar usando el siguiente codigo:

```
Sheets("ORIGEN").Range(Sheets("ORIGEN").Cells(Row - 2,1),Sheets("ORIGEN").Cells(Row - 2,3)).Copy
```

Si con estas dos opciones no te funciona, depura linea a linea y mira si el problema esta en el copy o en el paste. Paras el codigo tras el copy y haz tu el paste manualmente para asegurarte que copia correctamente.

suerte!